# Multiple select input by "Unique Select" with JSON Schema Form (Retool)

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema, multiple-select, react-jsonschema-forms, retool

In **Retool** with **JSON Schema Form**, I tried to make the multiple select input which cannot select the already selected options (means **unique select**) but what I could make is the one which can select the already selected options (means **ununique select**) as shown below.

As shown below, I can select the already selected option **"English"** so **"English"** is selected twice. In other words, I can still select **"English"** for the second multiple select input even though I've already selected **"English"** for the first multiple select input (means **ununique select**):

[image]

This is the **JSON Schema**:

```js
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "languages": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        enum: ['English', 'Japanese', 'Chinese'],
      },
    }
  }
}
```

However, rather than **"ununique select"** like above, what I really want is the **"unique select"**  which cannot select the already selected options like below:

[image]

Are there any ways to make the multiple select input which cannot select the already selected options(means **unique select**)?

Answer (score 2):

Add **"uniqueItems: true,"** under **"languages"**:

```js
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "languages": {
      "type": "array",
      uniqueItems: true, // Here
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        enum: ['English', 'Japanese', 'Chinese'],
      },
    }
  }
}
```

This way, you can make the multiple select input which cannot select the already selected options(means **unique select**):

[image]

[image]

In addition, if you add **"uniqueItems: false,"** under **"languages"**,

```js
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "languages": {
      "type": "array",
      uniqueItems: true, // Here
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        enum: ['English', 'Japanese', 'Chinese'],
      },
    }
  }
}
```

the result is the multiple select input which can select the already selected options (means **ununique select**):

[image]